# Get Value of MACD on different TimeFrame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How can you get the value of the Macd Line and Signal Line real-time from different timeframe. Like for example I am on a 4HR chart and I want to get the value of the Macd Line and Signal Line from the 1 hr timeframe.

I know how to get the value of the two lines it is just that I cannot solve or find the value from the other timeframe.
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `security` function to access **higher** timeframe data, but trying to access **lower** than your chart's timeframes will lead to unreliable results in Pine Script version < 5, as TV doesn't support intrabar data there. In Pine Script V5, an additional [request.security_lower_tf()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity_lower_tf) function was added to handle this case.

You can also include **tuple** in the `security` function calls

Daily MACD, signal and histogram data from the Daily chart.

```
[macdLineD, signalLineD, histLineD] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [macdLine, signalLine, histLine])
```

`Security` function could lead to **repainting**, check this article how to avoid the issue - https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/

non-repainting version use the previous resolution value with lookahead argument set to true:

```
[macdLineD, signalLineD, histLineD] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [macdLine[1], signalLine[1], histLine[1]], lookahead = true)
```

Answer (score -2):

With security Functions.
security(syminfo.tickerid,"{Your timeframe},